# How do I query just one level of a table-per-type mapping?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1's code first approach to map a class hierarchy to a series of tables.

I have the following classes defined:

```
[Table("FooBases")]
public class FooBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Table("Foo1s")]
public class Foo1 : FooBase
{
    public string Details { get; set; }
}

[Table("Foo2s")]
public class Foo2 : FooBase
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

So this will create three tables, where the common properties (Id and Name) are stored in a `FooBase` table.

In one particular case I am only interested in a list of names of any kind of `FooBase` object. I don't care whether it's a `Foo1` or a `Foo2`. I spin up a new data context and run a query like this:

```
var names = ctx.Set<FooBase>().Select(f => f.Name);
```

Now, I don't need the overhead of querying the `Foo1s` and `Foo2s` tables. I expect the query to just be a simple `SELECT Name FROM FooBases`. Instead, I get this:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
FROM  [dbo].[FooBases] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Foo1s] AS [Extent2]
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Foo2s] AS [Extent3]) AS [UnionAll1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [UnionAll1].[Id]
```

Is there a way to tell Entity Framework that I don't care about the other tables; that I just want data from the top level of the class hierarchy so there's no need to query anything other than the top level table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [well known issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/08/17/performance-considerations-when-using-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) with Table-per-type inheritance mapping. It should be addressed in [upcoming EFv4.2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/06/30/announcing-the-microsoft-entity-framework-june-2011-ctp.aspx) which should [improve the query generation for TPT inheritance](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/entity-framework-june-2011-ctp-tpt-inheritance-query-improvements/). At the moment there is no way to improve it.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Ladislav. Glad to know it's getting fixed.